# How to split JSON into 2 set of array using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json data and i am trying to split it into 2 sets of data arrays One json data will hold all the values from "Type1" data values and the 2nd json data will hold the rest values using jquery

**My Json code**

```
{
 "Type1" : "name",
   "1"   :"one",
   "2"   : "two"
}
{
"Type1" :"value",
  "3" :"three",
  "4" :"four"
}
```

Comment: What is your original JSON?

Comment: provide better description about the json original state to what you want to happen after process

Comment: split the string into two at the point where you have }{ then use JSON to parse each into an object

Comment: What is your expected output? How it look like?

Comment: i think your designing your json data in the wrong way. since json is an object.. try to figure out more how to work with json datas that will help your life more easier

Comment: Your code is not a valid json...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by just using javascript. Try this one, it worked in me.

```
var data = [
        {
            "Type1" : "name",
            "1"   :"one",
            "2"   : "two"
        },
        {
            "Type1" :"value",
              "3" :"three",
              "4" :"four"
        }
    ];

    var type1 = data[0];
    var type2 = data[1];
```

I hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you want to put all the values of Type1 in one array, and the rest values in another array.

You can just loop in the json data, for each iteration, put the values of Type1 in an array, and put the rest in the other array, like this :

```
var arrayType1 = [],
    arrayRest = [];

// loop in the json data
for(var indexGroup in jsonData){
    if(jsonData.hasOwnProperty(indexGroup)){
        // loop in the group in the json data
        for(var item in jsonData[indexGroup]){
            var group = jsonData[indexGroup];
            if(group.hasOwnProperty(item){
                if(item=="Type1"){
                    arrayType1.push(group[item]);
                }else{
                    arrayRest.push(group[item]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT : Since you know well the structure of the jsonData, and it does not inherite any properties from its superclass. You can delete the codes of checking own property, to make the code more clear :

```
if(jsonData.hasOwnProperty(indexGroup))
if(group.hasOwnProperty(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the console. You will get two arrays, the first containing the values of "Type1" key and the second with the rest keys values:

```js
var arr = [{
 "Type1" : "name",
   "1"   :"one",
   "2"   : "two"
},
{
"Type1" :"value",
  "3" :"three",
  "4" :"four"
}];

var typeArr = [];
var restArr = [];

for (i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
  for (n in arr[i]) {
    if (n == 'Type1') {
      typeArr.push(arr[i][n]); 
    } else {
      restArr.push(arr[i][n]);
    }
  }
}
console.log(typeArr);
console.log(restArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```